# Finding the optimal consumption bundle given the strictly concave utility function $v(x,y) = U(x) +y$?

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, optimization

I am also finding it difficult to understand what are the fundamental differences between analysing optimal bundles between concave and convex functions ?

Does it also happen that the optimal bundle in strictly concave function is $not $ a boundary condition ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you include a quasi-linear form of utility function in the title? Is quasi-linearity supposed to have any significance in your question? By "boundary condition" did you mean "corner solution"?

Comment: When you ask about the optimal bundle as a function, you probably mean as a function of parameters, but which parameters are you considering?